# Getting poles of a Gamma functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, series-expansion, physics

Why do the following 2 sequences give different answers?

- n = 1.5

  Series[Gamma[0.5 - n - x], {x, 0, 2}]
- Series[Gamma[-1 - x], {x, 0, 2}]

(..clearly the output from the second expression is correct since it has the 1/x pole..)

---

I want do similar Laurent series finding with products of Gamma functions like,

```
f[n_,x_] := (29/4)*((Gamma[
   0.5 - n - x] Gamma[(n + 1)/2 + x] Gamma[(n + 1)/2 + x])/(Gamma[
   1 - n/2] Gamma[1 - n/2] Gamma[1 + n + x]));
```

(at different values of "n")

I would think that doing, Series[f[1.5,x],{x,0,2}] should do.
But is there something I need to be careful about given the above kind of discrepancy?

- I eventually want to look at a sum of such "f" as above kind of functions and find the poles of the sum. Any cautions about that would be very helpful!

Comment: If you take the series `Series[Gamma[-a - x], {x, 0, 2}]` you get a series having `Gamma[-a]` now for a integer positive those functions are undefined. So, you can't just using one series to cover the whole behavior of this transcendental function. You have to have this in mind in the function you want to study.

Comment: @Spawn1701D This comment of yours is in reference to my "f"? What do you suggest I do?

Comment: it extents to f because if, say, $0.5-n = -\kappa,\ \kappa\epsilon I$ the expansion will be different, because of the pole.

Comment: Why are you using inexact numbers? Try e.g. `Series[1/2 - n - x, (* stuff *)]`...

Comment: @J.M Changing 0.5 to 1/2 doesn't remove the discrepancy. What do I do?

Comment: Don't use `1.5` either.

Comment: @Spawn1701D I am not quite getting you. Can you write down the command which would always gives the correct pole structure?

Comment: You have to use the series expansions found [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/06/01/05/01/)

Comment: `With[{n = 3/2}, Series[Gamma[1/2 - n - x], {x, 0, 2}]]`

Comment: @J.M WoW! With using fractions the discrepancy is gone! So whats the science behind it? So is that all that is there to be careful about for "f" and for sum of such "f"?

Comment: @Spawn1701D I know that Gamma function pole expansion. I want Mathematica to generate that for me - which is does - but in complicated cases like "f" and sum of such "f".

Comment: @user6818 It does it if it knows that you give a negative integer if you give an expression like $-n$ will use the generic formula. Do you want the series expansion for a generic $n$ or for a specific one?

Comment: Moral lesson: for symbolic work, avoid inexact numbers.

Comment: @Spawn1701D I would love to get it for generic "n" - as in get the pole structure of "f" as a function of "n" but I don't know how to get that to work - as of now I am doing it for specific "n". Also I guess pole structure is not additive right? As in if $f$ and $g$ are functions like the $f$ given then $pole [f+g] \neq pole[f] + pole[g]$..right? So i can't split the question into simpler parts either. Pole structure is multiplicative $pole [fg] = pole[f]pole[g]$

Comment: @user6818 unfortunately things are a little more complicated than that. $\Gamma$ function has poles the negative integers, your function $f$ has a more complicated set.

Comment: @Spawn1701D But no matter how complicated $f$ gets, Series[f[n,x],{x,0,2}] should always work and get me the poles..right?

Comment: @user6818 if you specify the $n$ yes if you leave it arbitrary no.

Comment: @Spawn1701D And I have been seeing that the poles I am getting are not additive over the functions. Sum of the poles of each such f is not the same as the pole of the sum of such f. Any comments? And about products?

Comment: @user6818 I don't know, say that $f=1/z$ and $g=a/z$ do you believe that the product rule for the poles apply?

Comment: @Spawn1701D I think the problem got sorted. The poles are both additive as well as multiplicative over meromorphic functions.

Comment: @user6818 did you find it in a book? Care to give me its reference? I would to take a look at it sometime and freshen up my knowledge of complex analysis!

Comment: Perhaps the answers to your questions are already at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21756/using-mathematica-to-find-poles-of-gamma-functions/21802#21802.